# How do I show that $-\frac{1}{e^x + 1} + 1 = \frac{e^x}{e^x + 1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, fractions

The expression is
$$-\frac{1}{e^x + 1} + 1 = \frac{e^x}{e^x + 1}$$

I would like help to get from the left side to the right side.

Comment: Put $t=e^x$, leads to $$\frac{-1}{1+t} +1 = \frac{t}{1+t}$$ in the next step we add $$\frac{-1}{1+t}$$ to  both sides.

Comment: Closely related question: [How to get from $\frac{x}{x+1}\;$ to $\;1 - \frac{1}{x+1}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259498/how-to-get-from-fracxx1-to-1-frac1x1)

Comment: Also closely related, grade 7 math http://teachers.sd43.bc.ca/syuen/Classroom%20Documents/Math/Math%20Makes%20Sense%207%20Text/mms7.pdf

Comment: It's quite simple actually. Maybe you could see it easier if you wrote 1 first and then that other term. so it looks like 1 - f(e^x). That expression looks easier than -f(e^x)+1 for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

One can write the $1=\frac{e^x+1}{e^x+1}$ in $\frac{-1}{e^x+1}+1$ to obtain $$\frac{-1}{e^x+1}+\frac{e^x+1}{e^x+1}=\frac{-1+e^x+1}{e^x+1}=\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}.$$

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

$$-\frac{1}{e^x + 1} + 1 = -\frac{1}{e^x + 1} + \frac{e^x+1}{e^x+1}= \frac{-1+e^x+1}{e^x+1} = \frac{e^x}{e^x+1}{}$$

Answer (score 1):

Simply compute the *LHS*..
$$-\frac{1}{e^x + 1} + 1 = \frac{-1 + e^x + 1}{e^x + 1} = \frac{e^x}{e^x + 1}$$

Comment: I don't see how this is a hint...

Comment: allright! edited .. now it's an answer

Answer (score 0):

you should take lcm: see my answer

$$-\frac{1}{e^x+1}+1=-\frac{1}{e^x+1}+\frac{1}{1}=\frac{-1+1*(e^x+1)}{1*(e^x+1)}=\frac{-1+e^x+1}{e^x+1}=\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align} \forall x\in\mathbb{R},\ \dfrac{-1}{e^x+1}+1-\left(\dfrac{e^x}{e^x+1}\right)&=\dfrac{-1}{e^x+1}+\dfrac{e^x+1}{e^x+1}-\dfrac{e^x}{e^x+1}\\
&=\dfrac{-1+e^x+1}{e^x+1}-\dfrac{e^x}{e^x+1}\\
&=\dfrac{e^x}{e^x+1}-\dfrac{e^x}{e^x+1}\\
&=0\\
&\square
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do simple addition. $$\frac{-1}{e^x+1}+1$$ $$=\frac{-1+e^x+1}{e^x+1}$$ $$=\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}$$

Comment: I have reread this answer multiple times and I don't get why it would be downvoted. Makes good sense to me!